# Where to find JDK 8 for ARM

Tags: java, oracle, arm, java-8

I went to the Oracle site to download the release JDK 8 for ARM and the version labeled as JDK 8 is actually JDK 7 update 40. Does anyone know where to find the JDK 8 for ARM or how to let Oracle know about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think it ll help you   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/java-embedded-java-se-download-359230.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

Answer (score 0):

On the [download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), the filename is jdk-8-linux-arm-vfp-hflt.tar.gz. Try again?

Answer (score 0):

The azul contains arm jdk support. you can try the https://www.azul.com/downloads/. Install the arm version using sdkman: https://sdkman.io/.