# Will x64 jdk-1.8 work in Mac with Apple Silicon (M1) Chip?

Tags: java, java-8, cassandra, apple-m1

I am trying to have JDK 8 run with cassandra 3.x in my dev-setup Mac with M1Pro Chip. Arm64 jdk-8 is currently unavailable currently.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524149/where-to-find-jdk-8-for-arm maybe

Comment: @f1sh There is no jdk-8 for mac arm64 in that page.

Answer (score 54):

Homebrew does not support OpenJDK@8 on Apple Silicon (M1/M2) but Zulu Community 8 is present as a cask. You just have to enable [cask-versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions) repository and install zulu8 cask.

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu8
```

It will install the JDK in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home`. You should then configure your JAVA_HOME variable for development tools to use it.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Please note that Zulu Community 8 will only be supported until March 2026.

Answer (score 11):

You *can* run Java for Intel Macs on Apple Silicon (ARM, Aarch64) via [*Rosetta 2*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2).

But for maximum performance, obtain an implementation of Java 8 built for Apple Silicon Macs.

> Arm64 jdk-8 is currently unavailable currently.

Not true.

You have a choice of vendors. I know [Azul Systems provides such products](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk). And others do as well. Try vendors providing JDK products, to see if they offer Java 8 on Apple Silicon Macs. Try vendors such as:

- [Adoptium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoptium)
- Azul Systems
- [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk)
- [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc)
- [SAP](https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/)
- [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/)
- Oracle
- IBM
- Red Hat
- … and more

Answer (score 7):

you can try the https://www.azul.com/downloads/. Install the arm version using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this link to install java 1.8 into your mac with M1/M2 chip. Apple uses [Rosetta2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2) for Mac transition to Apple silicon.

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-mac

Scroll down to java 1.8,
Go to the MacOS Version,
Click on the ARMx64 Version for M2 Chip,
Follow the onboarding process and simply install the java 1.8 for M2/M1.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to have Java8
`brew install adoptopenjdk8` or `brew install --cask temurin8`

Comment: There's no macOS aarch64 version.