# Installing JVM 8 on Mac with M1 chip

Tags: java, macos, apple-m1, grobid

I'm trying to install [GrObId](https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install-Grobid/) and it requires JVM8. Will installing [JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/install/installation-jdk-macos.html) work for this on an M1 Mac?

Comment: "Most recent JVM version (up to JVM 11) will work correctly". Is there any particular reason you're set on using Java 8?

Comment: it says v8 is the supported version

Comment: That quote about JVM 11 is right from the link you gave. The full quote is "GROBID requires a JVM installed on your machine, supported version is JVM 8. **Most recent JVM version (up to JVM 11) will work correctly**. CRF models will also work with JVM up to 14, but using the Deep Learning with JVM beyond 11 will lead to issues." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to use a *supported* version, not one that simply *works*, correct?

Comment: yes exactly !!!

Comment: Looks like Azul provides a JRE 8 compiled for M1 (arm64) macs. Select Zulu [here](https://www.azul.com/downloads/), then play with the filters to find the correct version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will x64 jdk-1.8 work in Mac with Apple Silicon (M1) Chip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769846/will-x64-jdk-1-8-work-in-mac-with-apple-silicon-m1-chip)

Comment: @rami_salazar Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 5):

### Install Azul's M1 native JDK 8.

You may obtain an installer for [Java 8 (LTS)](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk) . The current version is Azul Zulu: 8.64.0.19 (8u345b01) in .dmg format.

Open the disk image and install.

### Next you will need to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Open the Terminal.app and run this command:

```
% open .profile ; open .cshrc ; open .zshrc; open .login; open .bash_profile
The file /Users/risner/.zshrc does not exist.
The file /Users/risner/.login does not exist.
```

Ignore any "does not exist" errors. You should have a couple of files open.

If you have any files called .cshrc or .login open, add this end of the file:

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

If you have any .zshrc, .profile or .bash_profile open then add this line instead:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Next, quit terminal and reopen. You should now be able to install `GrObId`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install the openjdk 8 and the latest version 0.7.3 also supports JDK > 11. With the latest version you can install temurin 17 directly with homebrew.