# System.getProperty("os.arch") different between Java 17 and Java 8

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

I have this method

```java
static String getArchSuffix() {
    String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
    if (arch.equals("i686")) {
        return "x86";
    } else if (arch.equals("amd64")) {
        return "x86_64";
    } else if (arch.equals("nacl")) {
        return "armv7l";
    } else if (arch.equals("aarch64")) {
        return "armv7l";
    }
    return arch;
}
```

In Java 8, it worked well for my Macbook pro M2.

The result was:

```
arch = x86_64
```

Now after migrating to Java 17, I get

```
arch = aarch64
```

I expected the same behavior for the two versions. What am I missing?

I expected that this method works and outputs the same values for Java 17, and Java 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `os.arch` property is reporting the *native* instruction set of the JVM executable that is running, and that is different in *your* Java 8 and Java 17 cases.

Here's what I think has happened.

- The Java 8 installation you were previously using was a x86_64 build, and you were using MacOS's x86_64 emulation, [*Rosetta 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2).
- The Java 17 installation is a native ARM64 build.

---

> I'm expecting that this method works and output same values for jdk17 and jdk1.8.

That would only happen if the Java builds had the same target architecture.   If you wanted an ARM64 build for Java 8, you could potentially get one from a third party vendor; see [Will x64 jdk-1.8 work in Mac with Apple Silicon (M1) Chip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769846).

Answer (score 2):

You're now running on a JVM which is native aarch64 (ARM64), where previously you were running a x86_64 (AMD64) JVM which was translated to M2 using [*Rosetta 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2) technology.

To be clear, x86_64 is the Intel/AMD x86 64-bit instruction set, while the M2 is actually aarch64 (ARM64). So technically, the Java 8 version was 'lying' to you, because it actually ran on a x86-64 emulation layer.

Comment: *"So technically, the Java 8 version was 'lying' to you, because it actually ran on a x86-64 emulation layer."* - It's not a lie if you **unknowingly** say something that is untrue :-)

Comment: @StephenC Which is why I have lying in quotes.

Comment: We should judge the truth of the property value by the purpose of the property. If you want to know the architecture of the native libraries you can link to the JVM runtime, the answer was correct in either case. That’s not different to a 32 bit JVM reporting a 32 bit architecture despite running on a 64 bit CPU.